# Batch object recognition in images, not face recognition

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, batch-processing, image-recognition

I've faced a problem of recognizing objects (see attachment below) of some kind in large heap of images:

I have a lot of images (N*10^7 full size images), which I need to crop. Some images are images which contain faces, that need to be cropped by center.

Also there are some photos without faces. These also need to be cropped by center.

And I have some images which contain objects (not face) in the bottom part. So, I can't crop it by center (cause I don't like to cut the object).

Thus, I need a fast way to detect images of these kind and crop most of those white areas on the top and crop images to a `220 x 220 px` square with the object in the center. Is there any ready-to-go solution just-from-the-box? OpenCV didn't help much. Maybe you can advice something better?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s6yn.jpg

Comment: Does all the images have a white background?

Comment: not sure. maybe kind of gray, or whiteblue. Or with minor shadow.

Comment: You could try Otsu's method to extract the object from the background or active contours.